# Login to Yahoo Mail using mechanize with python

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I am trying to login myself to mail.yahoo using mechanize. I followed some tutorials/questions about this, but everything I try fails.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.open("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us")

#assert br.viewing_html()
print response.get_data()
br.select_form(nr=0)

br["login"] = "username"
br["passwd"] = "password"

try:
    response = br.submit()
print response.get_data()
    except HTTPError, e:
sys.exit("post failed: %d: %s" % (e.code, e.msg))
```

It seems my code failes because the username/password is wrong. I doubled checked!

Comment: Did you print the HTML and read it? If not, put it in a pastebin, remove your password if its in it, and then show it here. I'm sure the HTML response will give you your answer about what's going wrong.

Comment: you ever get this to work?